# How to get a total amount of cells per classification type in a raster in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, attribute-table, classification

I did an supervised classification for for this watershed.  The attribute table doesn't have the count for total number of cell for each classification.  I've created a field titled 'Count' with type 'Long', but I haven't figured out how to populate it.  The photo is just to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

-Using ArcGIS 10.1

-Supervised classification done on Landsat7 images that had multiple bands.  I don't know why the table has a red, green, and blue column

[image: Raster properties for the supervised classification image][image: Attribute table I'm working with]

Comment: How is it that the attribute table showing Red/Green/Blue values, when the output of classification approaches is a single band data.?

Comment: In which software have u done your classification?

Comment: If this was an Integer grid you would have a Value and Count column. I fear you are not telling us the whole story as pointed out by @Akhil an @msi_g!

Comment: Normally ERDAS generates these RGB colums. If i got you workaround is get the area for each class and divide this area by cell size(spatial resolution)-this is the number of cell for that class.

Comment: @msi_g as stated in the question I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.  I'm trying to find the area of the different classes.  I just asked about the cell number because I thought that was the only way to find the area for each class.  If you know of another way of getting the area of the classes I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: @Akhil I have no idea.  This is what the attribute table looked like after I did the classification, except for me adding the count column.  For this image I classified Landsat7 images which had multiple bands.  I also classified a Landsat8 image (not pictured), and the attribute table showed up with red, green, and blue columns as well. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: @Hornbydd what other information would give you the whole story? I just posted raster properties for this image and edited the post.  Let me know what might help you to answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain why your original raster does not have a populated count field - I thought it appeared by default for integer rasters.

In any case, you can get those values by:

1. Create a new integer raster, from your original, using [Int](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000008z000000). This will create a copy of the raster with Value and Count fields.
2. [Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) the new raster back to the original raster based on the Value fields in each.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this recently while using ArcGIS Pro (3.0.4). It may work for older versions of ArcGIS.
Classified raster attribute tables failed to display the "Count" column.
This was resolved by using the "[Build Raster Attribute Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/build-raster-attribute-table.htm)" tool.